# How to get the last visited route/state in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am working on a React application for windows mobile. My routes are defined like

```
<Route path='/' component={App} >
  <IndexRedirect to='/home' />
  <Route path='shows' component={ShowsListPage} />
  <Route path='show/:id' component={ShowPage} />
</Route>
```

I also have few other routes configured like above.

What i am trying to do is, when i navigate from page1 to page2, i want to get the page1 url or state or path in page2's component. Based on the last visited page, i need to some manipulations in the component.
I tried with `document.referrer`, which will give the last visited page url. But this is not showing anything when i test on windows environment. I tried few answers in stackoverflow, which are somewhat related to my question but none of them resolved this issue.

Is there any other way to get the last visited page url? Also is there any way to get the complete history details?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this: [setRouteLeaveHook](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/ConfirmingNavigation.md).

So that when exiting from a route you can save the route and/or the state where you want and use it in when you want when the next route is entered.